# can not import Protocol from typing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have fresh installed Python 3.7-32 on Windows 10.

I want to try Protocols python approach and I do next:

file test_protocols.py with only one row:

```
from typing import Protocol
```

then:

```
>python test_protocols.py
```

And I have next error message that is needed to be explained:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_protocols.py", line 1, in <module> 
    from typing import Protocol
ImportError: cannot import name 'Protocol' from 'typing' (C:\Programing\Python\Python37-32\lib\typing.py)
```

What do I do wrong?

Maybe I have read PEP-0544 wrong but from my point of view I do the same as it is documented.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of January 20, 2019, [PEP 544](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/)'s status is `Draft`. As far as I understand, it's not implemented in CPython yet.

**UPD**: it should work since Python 3.8, try updating.

Comment: oh, exactly. Thanks a lot. Will try another approach like python-interface library from pypi.org/project/python-interface.

Comment: PEP 544 has been accepted into Python 3.8, so there the import works.

Answer (score 16):

If it does not exist in typing do

```
pip install typing_extensions

from typing_extensions import Protocol
```

Depending upon OS and Python version Protocol class might be within typing module or in typing_extensions.

Answer (score 7):

In the [implementation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/#implementation) section of [PEP 544](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/), it says

> The `mypy` type checker fully supports protocols (modulo a few known
>   bugs). This includes treating all the builtin protocols, such as
>   `Iterable` structurally. The runtime implementation of protocols is
>   available in `typing_extensions` module on PyPI.

Thus, in your code, add `from typing_extensions import Protocol`.