# stackstac on Google Colab results in ImportError: cannot import name 'Protocol' from 'typing'

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm unable to install stackstac on Google Colab. This is reproducible with the code below.

```
!pip install stackstac
import stackstac
```

outputs:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-c01f370957f7> in <module>()
      1 get_ipython().system('pip install stackstac')
----> 2 import stackstac

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/stackstac/rio_reader.py in <module>()
      5 import threading
      6 import weakref
----> 7 from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, Optional, Protocol, Tuple, Type, Union
      8 
      9 import numpy as np

ImportError: cannot import name 'Protocol' from 'typing' (/usr/lib/python3.7/typing.py)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[Same issue on a local instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54274630/can-not-import-protocol-from-typing) how ever that solution doesn't translate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Protocol` was introduced to `typing` as of Python 3.8, as can be seen [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol). You appear to be running Python 3.7, based on your file paths - upgrade to use Python 3.8 or later if you can.